# The World • It Disintegrates

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon, sutras

Friends, I am looking for a sutta from the Pali Canon wherein the Buddha, expounding the nature of the *world*, goes somewhat like this :

> And what is the world ? That which disintegrates is the world. That’s why we call it is called 'the world'.

Thank you for your very much appreciated help.

With gratitude.

Answer (score 2):

> It is ‘breaking up,’ bhikshu, therefore it is called ‘world’.”

[(Lujjati) Loka Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/7.3-Lujjati-Loka-S-s35.82-piya.pdf)